# Compiling against modified library in linux

Tags: compilation, linker, configure, pkg-config

I've compiled mplayer2 against the prebuilt libavcodec library in ubuntu. It crashes under specific conditions.

Judging my the error message spat out, the problem lies with libavcodec. So what I would like to is do experiment with some of the libavcodec code. i.e. Compile my own version of libavcodec and then compile mplayer2 against that.

pkg-config will point towards the installed libavcodec libraries from ubuntu's apt-get. How do I point it to my own version of libavcodec? Or tell the configure script to use my version?

Comment: check the output of configure --help: this will show you if you can substitute a different libavcodec

Comment: @rwst, i guess I could try --extra-libs=FLAGS